# jQuery datatables allow select on row reorder drag handle

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I want to use both the select and rowReorder extensions.  With the defaults for rowReorder the first column is the drag handle, but clicking cells in the first column won't select the row.

I would typically want the whole row to be both a drag handle and allow selection by clicking.  Is there a way to get the rowReorder to allow the click event to make it to the select extension?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jinglesthula/dzLc29mm/)

```
<table id="example">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th>foo</th>
    <th>bar</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  select: true,
  rowReorder: { selector: 'tr' }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rowReorder event to select the row. You can see how to use this event on the following link:

https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/events.html

The following code shows how to select the row clicking on the cells in the first column while using rowReorder:

```
table.on( 'row-reorder', function ( e, diff, edit ) {
  var index = edit.triggerRow[0][0];
  table.rows(index).select();
});
```